# perl inheritance and directory structure

Tags: perl

I'm trying to learn inheritance in Perl.

This is my directory structure:
perldir
perldir\child.pl
perldir\Mylib
perldir\Mylib\Parent.pm

**Parent.pm**

```
package Parent;

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { _first => shift, _last => shift };
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub getFirstName {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{ _first };
}

1;
```

**child.pl**

```
package Child;

use parent 'Mylib::Parent';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Parent->new( shift, shift );
    bless $self, $class;
}

my $obj = new Child('Jack', 'Sparrow');
print $obj->{_first},' ',$obj->{_last};
print "\n",$obj->getFirstName();  #Error
```

The error thrown on the last line is: Can't locate object method "getFirstName" via package "AChild" at child.pl line 13;

The program works if I do one of the following:
1. I have both the files under directory Mylib.
2. I replace

```
use parent 'Mylib::Parent'
```

with

```
use Mylib::Parent;
@ISA = ('Parent');
```

Is it possible to get the program to work using 'use parent' and with the child class in a different directory?

==========================
**UPDATED the question** based on [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s answer.

Ok I changed the classes to reflect the following:

**Parent.pm**

```
package Mylib::Parent;

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { _first => shift, _last => shift };
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub getFirstName {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{ _first };
}

1;
```

**child.pl**

```
package Child;

use parent 'Mylib::Parent';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Mylib::Parent->new( shift, shift );
    bless $self, $class;
}

my $obj = new Child('Jack', 'Sparrow');
print $obj->{_first},' ',$obj->{_last};
print "\n",$obj->getFirstName();
```

The above works fine. Now consider I want another child class to be in the same directory as Parent.pm.

**perldir\Mylib\ChildTwo.pl**

```
package ChildTwo;   #or package Mylib::ChildTwo;

use parent 'Mylib::Parent'; #or use parent 'Parent';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Mylib::Parent->new( shift, shift ); #or Parent->new(shift, shift);
    bless $self, $class;
}

my $obj = new ChildTwo('Jack', 'Sparrow'); #or new Mylib::ChildTwo('Jack','Sparrow');
print $obj->{_first},' ',$obj->{_last};
print "\n",$obj->getFirstName();

1;
```

The above does not work. Can I get ChildTwo.pl to work along with Child.pl without using 'use lib'?

Comment: 'Parent' ne 'AParent'.

Comment: If it's a child class, it should go to a pm file, not pl.

Comment: I understand the conventions. I'm trying to understand how to get both .pl's to work accessing the same Parent.pm

Comment: Add `use lib '..'` to it.

Comment: I was trying to see if it can be done without use lib.

Comment: It makes no sense. Scripts don't go to the same directory hierarchy as modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to understand how classes can use each other when residing in various packages. It seems like, unlike Java where 'lib' generally means 3rd party jars, a lib in Perl denotes the root containing all the packages specific to a script.

> Seems like **'use lib (dirpath)'** has to be used. **See usage in
>   ChildThree.pm**.

**Directory structure:**

/perldir/child.pl 
/perldir/use_child_two.pl 
/perldir/use_child_three.pl 
/perldir/Mylib/Parent.pm 
/perldir/Mylib/ChildTwo.pm 
/perldir/Secondlib/ChildThree.pm

**/perldir/Mylib/Parent.pm**

```
package Mylib::Parent;

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { _first => shift, _last => shift };
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub getFirstName {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{ _first };
}

1;
```

**/perldir/child.pl**

```
package Child;

use parent 'Mylib::Parent';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Mylib::Parent->new( shift, shift );
    bless $self, $class;
}

my $obj = new Child('Jack', 'Sparrow');
print $obj->{_first},' ',$obj->{_last};
print "\n",$obj->getFirstName();
```

**/perldir/Mylib/ChildTwo.pm**

```
package Mylib::ChildTwo;

use parent 'Mylib::Parent';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Mylib::Parent->new( shift, shift );
    bless $self, $class;
}

1;
```

**/perldir/use_child_two.pl**

```
use Scalar::Util ('blessed');

use Mylib::ChildTwo;

my $obj = new Mylib::ChildTwo('Jack', 'Sparrow');
print "\n Class: ", blessed ( $obj );
print "\n ",$obj->{_first},' ',$obj->{_last};
print "\n ",$obj->getFirstName();

1;
```

**/perldir/Secondlib/ChildThree.pm**

```
package Secondlib::ChildThree;

use lib '/perldir';     #Adds directories to search path to discover 
                        #package structure and finding module 'Mylib::Parent'
use parent 'Mylib::Parent';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = Mylib::Parent->new( shift, shift );
    bless $self, $class;
}

1;
```

**/perldir/use_child_three.pl**

```
use Scalar::Util ('blessed');

use Secondlib::ChildThree;

my $obj = new Secondlib::ChildThree('Jack', 'Sparrow');
print "\n Class: ", blessed ( $obj );
print "\n ",$obj->{_first},' ',$obj->{_last};
print "\n ",$obj->getFirstName();

1;
```

Comment: You can use multiple `lib`s.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make up your mind: either the parent package's name is `Parent`, then in `child.pl`:

```
use parent 'Parent';
```

and tell perl where to search for it:

```
perl -IMylib child.pl
```

or use [lib](http://p3rl.org/lib)

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/Mylib";
```

Or, the package's name is `Mylib::Parent`, then you have to fix the package declaration:

```
package Mylib::Parent;
```

and call the correct constructor:

```
my $self = Mylib::Parent->new( shift, shift );
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `package` in normal Perl scripts by default. The `package` declaration is used to create a new *name space* to prevent naming collisions between modules.

For simplicity, you don't have to create module directories for defining packages. In fact, it's not uncommon in object oriented Perl to define your classes in your main program if they aren't going to be shared between other programs.

Here's a simple inheritance example. I create two *objects*. `$wife` is a class `Person` while `$me` is a subclass of Person called `Developer`. Notice that I don't have `new` or `name` <strike>subroutines</strike> ..I mean.. ***methods*** defined in my `Developer` class. Those get inherited by my `use parent -norequire qw(Person);` statement.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my $wife  = Person->new();
$wife->name("Susan");
$wife->occupation("Quantum Physicist");

say "Name: " . $wife->name;
say "Occupation: " . $wife->occupation . "\n";

my $me = Developer->new("Bob");
$me->programming_language("Perl");

say "Name: " . $me->name;
say "Language: " . $me->programming_language;

########################################################################
########################################################################

package Person;

sub new {
    my $class           = shift;
    my $name            = shift;
    my $occupation      = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;

    $self->name($name);
    $self->occupation($occupation);
    return $self;
}

sub name {
    my $self            = shift;
    my $name            = shift;

    if ( defined $name ) {
        $self->{NAME} = $name;
    }
    return $self->{NAME};
}

sub occupation {
    my $self            = shift;
    my $occupation      = shift;
    if ( defined $occupation ) {
        $self->{OCCUPATION} = $occupation;
    }
    return $self->{OCCUPATION};
}

package Developer;
use parent -norequire, qw(Person);

sub programming_language {
    my $self            = shift;
    my $language        = shift;

    if ( defined $language ) {
        $self->{LANGUAGE} = $language;
    }

    return $self->{LANGUAGE};
}
```

It's possible to use the `SUPER` class to force your subclass to use the superclass definition:

I could have defined a `new` <strike>subroutine</strike>, ...uh... <strike>method</strike>, ...no, uh... ***constructor*** in my Developer class too:

```
package Developer;

...

sub new {
    my $class           = shift;
    my $name            = shift;
    my $language        = shift;
    my $occupation      = "Code Slinger";

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;       # Defines a Developer or subclass object

    $self->SUPER::name($name); # Sets the name of my Developer
    $self->SUPER::occupation($occupation); # We know the occupation
    return $self;
}
```

Now, if I request `$me->occupation`, it'll return `Code Slinger`.